# How can I know when an object has performed an action?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'd like to create a `Service` that's capable of creating a number of objects, where each object connects to the internet and downloads some JSON data and a photo. Most of this is pretty straight forward, but I want it to happen one at a time, i.e. a new object cannot be created until the first object has completed its actions.

What's the best way for my `Service` to know when an object has performed its actions?

Here's a very rough illustration of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: What other restriction is there? why can't you keep a reference in the Object instance to the Service (and viceversa if you are afraid the object will be GC) and when you are done you call a method in the service?

Comment: I've previously been calling a method in the Service, but I was wondering if there's a better way to do it. It seems a bit naughty to do it like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? When the object creation is complete, broadcast an intent (you could use `LocalBroadcast` for example, if you want it to be private).

In your `Service`, register for the above mentioned broadcast, and when it is received, perform the next task.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).  In normal usage, each `Intent` it receives is processed sequentially and is already in a background thread, so you don't even need to do your network activity in an `AsyncTask`. Easy.

Alternately, put all your things in a `Queue` and have the "do next thing" call happen as a result of the `onPostExecute()` call in `AsyncTask`s.

```
Queue<YourObject> unfinished = getQueue();
List<YourObject> finished = new LinkedList<YourObject>();
Handler handler = new Handler(){
  handleMessage(Message m){
     // Object populated!  Start next?  Blink lights?  Whatever.
  }
}

AsyncTask t = new AsyncTask<...>(handler) {
  Handler h;
  public AsyncTask<...>(Handler h) {
    this.h = h;
  }

  protected V doInBackground(YourObject o) {
    // Network stuff, populate the thing
    return popualtedThing();
  }

  protected V onPostExecute(YourObject o) {
    h.sendMessage(Message.obtain(0,o);
  }
}.execute();
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. I'm not looking to create a number of Intents or Services. I need to create objects from a Service.

Comment: The `IntentService` implementation -- you extend the one provided by the OS -- would create the objects without getting in the way of each other.  You're then free to send the created objects wherever you want.

Comment: I'm not using Intents, I'm using objects.

Comment: You're probably better off with my second suggestion in any case.  I'll edit my answer to elaborate.

Comment: The syntax and method signatures probably aren't perfect, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use listeners.  Have the background service register as a listener to the object instance and when the object instance is does it just calls back to all the listeners.